# NHibernate: row/result counting: Projection.RowCount() VS. Projection.Count()

Tags: nhibernate, count, projection, rowcount

What is the exact difference between NHibernates

```
Projection.RowCount()
```

and

```
Projection.Count()
```

when we are looking for number of rows/results?

Answer (score 1):

Projection.Count expects you to pass a property that you want a count on i.e

```
Projection.Count("propertyName")
```

which transalates to the following in SQL

```
select Count(this.whateverNhibernateConvention) from table as this
```

where as for Projection.RowCount you dont need to pass anything which translates to

```
select Count(1) from table as this
```

I think I expect the above to be the case

Comment: In the second expression, shouldn't this be `select Count(*)` ? I do not know in what `select count(1)` results, but i think (at least in Transact-SQL) it should be "count(*)" to match your second explanation?

Comment: Nope select count(1) is perfectly fine.. The COUNT function does not need to retrieve all fields from the table as it had to when you used the COUNT(*) syntax. It will merely retrieve the numeric value of 1 for each record that meets your criteria. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Note the query cost is the same and it will not matter what you use.. Count(1) is Count(*) in disguise

Comment: I got better performance using Projections.Count(Projections.Id()) instead of Projection.RowCount()